# batch file trying to copy one file to c drive

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am new to batch files

```
cd..
cd downloads
copy "note.bat" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer"
pause
```

This is my code to copy a file from downloads location I want to copy to the location when run as administration.

[image]

Comment: When i added xcopy now i get access dinied c:note.bat

Comment: Running a batch script as an Administrator makes the script start in `C:\Windows\system32` instead of whatever directory it is currently in (as shown by your image). Instead of using `cd ..` and then `cd downloads`, instead `cd` to the full path of where note.bat is located.

Comment: `CD %~dp0\..\downloads`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this.

```
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto Defense )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:Defense
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
::-----------------------------------------------        
@Echo off
:: ------------EXTRA CODE TO CHANGE
Echo Copying Files...
cd/
cd %USERPROFILE%
cd downloads
copy "note.bat" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer"
Echo Done!
```

Let me explain the code, all the code from `REM  --> Check for permissions` to

`:: ------------EXTRA CODE TO CHANGE` makes sure that we have admin rights, if we don't have then we see if UAC is disabled or enabled. If it is disabled then the batch starts as admin but if it is Enabled it asks for UAC prompt. As it is running as admin then the location would not be in your `%USERPROFILE%` but in `C:\Windows\System32`. For that it does the command `cd/` which will go to the root of the current drive, i.e `C:`. It then goes to your Profile and into downloads and then copies all the things to your specified Destination.

Hope it helps

Regards,